# Overrride Form Background Color onfocus using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, overriding

At the WordPress site http://tinyurl.com/nzm9orn using Lingonberry theme I am trying to overrride the background color for the text area. It is now:

```
.content form input[type="text"]:focus, .content form input[type="email"]:focus, .content form input.password:focus, .content form textarea:focus {
    background-color: #2D3642;
    border-color: #2B323A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: medium none;
}
```

I tried to override with my WordPress child theme CSS using !important using similar code, but it did not work. Don't really like using that override anyways.. Then I tried

```
/* Comment Box onfocus color */

.single .content form input[type="text"]:focus, .single  .content form input[type="email"]:focus, .single  .content form input.password:focus, .single  .content form textarea:focus {
    background-color: #fafafa; /*gray*/
}
```

And that also does not work. Any ideas what I am missing?

P.S. Similar issue with the post comment button. Can't find the CS override somehow

Comment: cant you just change it in the style.css rather than try to override it?

Comment: Nope. Parent theme will get automatic updates so its stylesheet should not be touched or changes made will be lost every now and then. That is why WordPress recommends child themes with their own stylesheet for changes. And that normally works just fine. Seem to be missing something. Been driving me nuts..

Comment: ok what about .content form textarea#comment input[type="text"]:focus

Comment: It seems a parsing error might not load the entire child theme stylesheet well: `Sorry! We found the following errors (1)
URI : TextArea
313  .content-inner:before  Parse Error .content-inner { width: 87.5%; float: right; position: relative; padding: 5.5%; box-shadow: none; } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in my child theme stylesheet. A curly brace was missing causing a parsing error:

```
313     .content-inner:before   Parse Error .content-inner { width: 87.5%; float: right; position: relative; padding: 5.5%; box-shadow: none; }
```

After I added the curly brace the standard overrride:

```
.content form textarea:focus
{
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
}
```

did work :)

Comment: ahhhhhhh your still using !important though :-)

Comment: @Richlewis sometimes, we come against with to use !important tag, I never recommend to use it, it is an old debug tool but, you know solution is solution if it does not hurt the system

Comment: @Richlewis Adjusted. `!important` was not necessary. It cascades very nicely now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have added this at the end of your stylesheet  and it works

```
.content form input[type="text"]:focus,
.content form input[type="email"]:focus,
.content form input.password:focus,
.content form textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #2B323A;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

and change the values accordingly.

Better have custom sytles in a new stylesheet and ref it in your HTML

Comment: I just added this to the stylesheet: 
`.content form input[type="text"]:focus,
.content form input[type="email"]:focus,
.content form input.password:focus,
.content form textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-color: #2B323A;
    color: #FFF;
}`
and it does not seem to work..

Comment: weird i added css and went with local modifications in chrome and its working

Answer (score 1):

1st Solution id by id

```
input#author:focus {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

2nd :for every input that you want to change add a global named class then determine the attributes like

```
<input id="author" class="GlobalName" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" size="30">

<input id="email"  class="GlobalName" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" value="" size="30">
```

in your style

```
input.GlobalName:focus
{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

3rd solu

```
.content form input[type="text"]:focus, .content form input[type="email"]:focus, .content form input.password:focus, .content form textarea:focus
{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: I also tried your code solution 1 and I see no changes either. Odd.

Comment: I think you are missing something,1st are you  linking your style right ?, 2nd Template may change style for the text boxes by javascript, did you check for it? 3rd how about solution 2, is it working?